# RestSharp api to post into tumblr with C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, restsharp

I am using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) api to post text/images into tumblr. I have this piece of code which I had used to post data into tumblr. It used to post data successfully into tumblr

```
        var restClient = new RestClient("http://tumblr.com/api/write");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddParameter("email", "xxxxx@abc.com");
        request.AddParameter("password", "whatever");
        request.AddParameter("type", "regular");
        request.AddParameter("title", "My post to tumblr");
        request.AddParameter("body", "<b>I am now on tumblr");
        IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

But now when I am testing it, it gets executed but posts nothing to tumblr. What am I missing here ?

Comment: What does `response` says?

Comment: It says authentication failed. But not sure why as it is used to work before.